# API console in wso2

Tags: url, wso2, uri, wso2-api-manager

I have below URL -

http://localhost:8280/ukAddress/v1/NR12GG/bluemill

in which my base url is http://localhost:8280/ukAddress/v1 & need to pass /NR12GG/bluemill as parameter from API console so that /NR12GG/bluemill will get added to the actual url defined in config xml.
How can i achieve this from API console.

THanks,
Amith

Answer (score 1):

You can use  `/{streetAddress1}/{streetAddress2}` and, you can provide `{uri.var.streetAddress1}` and `{uri.var.streetAddress2}` to target backend URL.

You can refer [HTTP Endpoint](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/HTTP+Endpoint) for more details